# What are some jSoup optimization tips?

Tags: java, optimization, jsoup

What are some tips one can keep in mind to speed up jSoup? I am pretty new to using jSoup and any advice about things I should do, things I should avoid, etc. would be most appreciated.

I just want to know some general things so that I won't slow down my own software.

For example, what is faster:

```
doc.select("[class=foo]:eq(0)").first()
```

or

```
doc.select("[class=foo]").first()
```

or

```
doc.select("[class=foo]:lt(1)").first()
```

Stuff like that.

Comment: I'm looking into something similar right now, but my my main "problem" is the endless wait of the .Parse method :(. I think that you can check things like these by printing something in your console, and see how fast you got the result. But for me, I have had no trouble with speed when it comes to the .Select function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try this tip (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10291833)):

not great

```
for (Element link : links)
```

better

```
int i;
Element tempLink;
for (i=0;i<links.size();i++) {
   tempLink = links.get(i);
}
```