# A way to estimate or predict Jsoup processing time of a chunk of HTML?

Tags: performance, optimization, jsoup

Some web pages that I process in Jsoup are heavy. By "heavy" I mean the page either contains lots of HTML (let's assume the page has already been downloaded), or it requires several iterations on the *same* document (created only once via [Jsoup.parse()](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/input/parse-document-from-string)).

For that reason, I would like to present to the user a progress bar with a guesstimate of how much time is left.

One approach is to just measure the volume of HTML (in KB or MB) and come up with a speed factor (unfortunately, totally dependent on speed of the system this code runs on).

Another approach is to count the [number of nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11291133/1357272)?

Due to the obvious in-deterministic nature of this, am I calling for trouble?

Ideas of better ways to handles this?

Comment: Can you give more example of the type of processing?  In my experience the Jsoup.parse usually is the performance bottleneck on large html's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarizing the answers so far: No, it is **not** possible to estimate or predict Jsoup processing time of a chunk of HTML.

The reason is, aside from the fact that `Jsoup.parse()` is the time-consuming component, Jsoup can run on many platforms/devices, some are extremely slow, some are very fast and there isn't a way (wait) for Jsoup to correlate its processing stages/operations with the architecture on which it runs.

Answer (score 0):

What I'd tell you to try is:

```
long start = System.currentTimeInMilis();
//Processing
long end = System.currentTimeInMilis();

long timeToProcess = end - start;
```

But I really think this is useless, since you depend on the page server, internet speed, processing power. There's just too much to predict. Also... The Jsoup selector API is **EXTREMELY** fast. Also.. The time that it'll take to connect is the longer wait. Which you truly cannot predict. Hope that helped